# Calculate yearly expiry in MySQL from static date

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

This might be simple but my brain has melted after a long day of non stop coding, and I'm running out of paper fast...

I'm trying to figure out a yearly expiry formula to calculate in a stored procedure.

Simplified table:

```
Security_Table
-----------------
User_ID [int]
Join_Date [DateTime]
Expired [VARCHAR]
```

So if a user joined on 2010-01-11 `Expired` would update to `"TRUE"` today, same goes for someone who joined on 2009-01-11 as it's a recurring expiry.

I'm running the procedure on a daily basis through scheduled tasks, would comparing the day and month be suffice? Obviously accounting for a leap year.

```
UPDATE Security_Table SET Expired = 'TRUE' WHERE DATE_FORMAT(Join_Date,'%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d')
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: Note; that specific code doesn't account for leap year *(You'll still compare a join date of '02-29' to '02-28' or '03-01')*.  But yes, such logic works in principle.  It has down sides that can be overcome with an alternative approach, as discussed briefly in my answer.

Comment: @pilcrow im struggling to find the edit you made on my question? - not to worry got it, you've changed the order of my example dates to ISO standards.

Comment: Yup.  I confess I stared dumbly at your original question for a moment thinking, "How can he say that a Join_Date of November first expires a year later on January eleventh?"  That's what happens when you're steeped in American date notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `WHERE month = month and date = date`.  *(Though be careful of 29th Feb as a join date.)*

This does, however, mean you have to scan to whole table/index looking for matches.  If you have a large table, this may be a problem.

I would think that in this case you're better off setting an expiry date value.  Then checking that...

```
WHERE
  expiry_date <= CURDATE()
```

When some-one renews you can update the expiry.  `SET expiry_date = DATE_ADD(expiry_date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)`.  You may have a new offer for 13 months for the price of 12, and setting the expiry lets you be flexible like that.  It's even immune to the 29th Feb problem.  In terms of reliability; if your batch process fails, running it a day late won't make you miss a bunch of people...

Comment: Adding an explicit "EXPIRY_DATE" is definitely good practice IMO.

Comment: It decouples the logic, and decoupling is almost as good as, wait, no, that's rude...

Comment: Yep that's a good point, however doesn't your solution also check all rows regardless to compare the CURDATE? Im not sure what the trade off would be over compare value against compare DATE_FORMAT. I like the reliability of your method though, especially when relying on Windows Scheduled Task and the leap year. Will tweak the DB tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: @rocky - The difference is that if you build an index on `expiry_date`, the optimiser can SEEK the records that match.  With the other example (comparing only month and date), the SEEK can't happen and a SCAN happens instead.  It's the difference between flicking through a book and checking every page, or using the index to determine which page to jump to.

Comment: @Dems thanks for the clarification and your input, saved a tired head! :)

Answer (score 1):

This query will simply check the Month and Day of every Join_Date against today, If you joined on Feb 29th, it will expire on Feb 28th or it will take 4 years to expire.

```
UPDATE Security_Table
SET Expired='TRUE'
WHERE Expired='FALSE'
AND 
(
    (DATE_FORMAT(Join_Date,'%m-%d')='02-29' AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d')='02-28')
    OR
    (DATE_FORMAT(Join_Date,'%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d'))
);
```

You should also index the table so that only those records that have Expired='FALSE' are examined.

```
ALTER TABLE Security_Table ADD INDEX (Expired,Join_Date);
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: And will yield a full table/index scan.